# Parse HTML snippet with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to parse an HTML document with **awk**.

The document contains several `<div class="p_header_bottom"></div` blocks

```
 <div class="p_header_bottom">
    <span class="fl_r"></span>
    287,489 people
  </div>
  <div class="p_header_bottom">
    <span class="fl_r"></span>
    5 links
  </div>
```

I am using

`awk  '/<div class="p_header_bottom">/,/<\/div>/'`

to receive all such div's.

How I can get `287,489` number from first one?

Actually `awk  '/<\/span>/,/people/'` doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Why awk for parsing HTML? Use a better tool like PHP and its DOM parser

Comment: @anubhava because I need just few items of information from one page, and `curl | awk ` background tasks spawned by bash script do 10000 pages in ~ one minute. PHP will be too expensive from both memory and CPU point of view.

Comment: I'm not too sure about PHP being expensive since it can do both curl part and later parsing part in same code so essentially you'll be invoking only 1 binary from command line. More importantly parsing using DOM will be accurate also. Only if you're 100% sure of the location and organization of this HTML then go for sed/awk for parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk), and assuming that the only digits and commas within each `<div> </div>` block occur in the numeric portion of interest

```
awk -v RS='<[/]?div[^>]*>' '/span/ && /people/{gsub(/[^[:digit:],]/, ""); print}' file.txt
```

Comment: @glennjackman, good catch, fixed. Not sure why `**` works though!